# Tension in Spring

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, spring

When spring is within elastic limit the tension in Spring is equal in magnitude to force applied for deforming it but when it has reached its elastic limit and more force is applied so that it's permanently deformed and we keep on applying force then tension in spring will not equal to applied force right?

Answer (score 0):

The tension in spring will always be equal to applied force to balance the net force.The spring become easier to extend after the limit of proportionality.

This happens because after the limit, the spring loses its elastic properties; the spring stops snapping back to it’s original shape, and the deformations become permanent. The new shape becomes the baseline shape to which the spring will return.

This alters the local structural orientation of the material, causing the spring as an object to have different properties than it did before deforming, which often includes a **weaker overall resistance** to deformation, changes in the spring’s k constant, or a **lower force requirement to reach the limit of proportionality again.**
Once the force exceeds that which is required to reach the limit of proportionality, the amount of deformation that occurs with increased force increases exponentially.

Comment: I believe the tension in the spring will always equal the applied force. When you say "the spring becomes easier to extend after the limit of proportionality" simply means the relationship between force and displacement no longer follows Hooke's law beyond the elastic limit.

Comment: You have a point ! @Bob D

Comment: You Are right @Bob D ,Sorry for misconception